# How to get this values form this data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
envelope:'{"to":["reply-to-501-4455@email.ashishbhangade.com"],"from":"Tway"}'
```

here my object data and i want find values only 501 and 4455 (every time this values are dynamic not static values) so how to get please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way to dynamic values

```js
const split = '{"to":["reply-to-501-4455@email.ashishbhangade.com"],"from":"Tway"}'.split('-')

const code1 = split[2]
const arrWithCode2 = split[3].split('@')
const code2 = arrWithCode2[0]

console.log(code1, code2)
```

If "reply-to-"  and codes length don`t change

```js
const msg = '{"to":["reply-to-501-4455@email.ashishbhangade.com"],"from":"Tway"}'

const code1 = msg.substring(17, 20)
const code2 = msg.substring(21, 25)

console.log(code1, code2)
```

Comment: Yes, but this values are dynamic if it's value length increase that time it is not work.
Thanks!

Comment: I add new solution!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with `string.includes`?

```js
const envelope = {"to":["reply-to-501-4455@email.ashishbhangade.com"],"from":"Tway"}

console.log(
envelope.to.some(pr => pr.includes("501")),
envelope.to.some(pr => pr.includes("4455"))
)
```

Comment: Yup, i agree but this is dynamic values not static.

Comment: You mean the whole object structure might change?

Comment: Not hole only "reply-to-" is static and other all are dynamic.